# VBA to click button with different span innertext

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I can't figure out how to click the button in the html below

```
<button class="dt-button buttons-collection buttons-colvis" tabindex="0" aria-controls="theDataTable" aria-haspopup="true" title="Choose columns to display from a list">
<span>Show/Hide Columns</span>
```

I tried:

```
Set goBtn = ie.document.querySelector("dt-button buttons-collection buttons-colvis")
 goBtn.Click
 For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If InStr(ele.innerText, "Status") > 0 Then ele.Click
 Next
```

I also am not sure how to click

```
<button class="dt-button buttons-columnVisibility active" tabindex="0" aria-controls="theDataTable">
<span>Status</span></button>
<button class="dt-button buttons-columnVisibility active" tabindex="0" aria-controls="theDataTable">
<span>Conditions</span></button>
```

I tried:

```
 Set goBtn = ie.document.querySelector("dt-button buttons-columnVisibility active").innerText("Status")
 goBtn.Click
 ie.document.getElementById("save-list-link").Click
```

Both give me a run-time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have spaces in the class name.

---

**For your first query:**

```
ie.document.querySelector("dt-button.buttons-collection.buttons-colvis").Click
```

**See query here:**

[image: css query]

This assumes it is the first element with that class name that you are after. Otherwise, you need to use `.querySelectorAll` and index into the `nodeList` returned to get the item required e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("dt-button.buttons-collection.buttons-colvis").item(1).Click '<==random example.
```

---

**Same idea with the second of your queries:**

```
.dt-button.buttons-columnVisibility.active
```

This time you know there is more than one matched element, so you use `.querySelectorAll` and index into `nodeList`:

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".dt-button.buttons-columnVisibility.active").item(0).Click '<==status.
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".dt-button.buttons-columnVisibility.active").item(1).Click '<==conditions.
```

**CSS query:**

[image: query]

You need to check these are the right indices for your entire HTML document.

---

**Element not found:**

You need to ensure page has loaded before attempting to select i.e.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

after the initial URL navigation. For slow loading pages you may need an additional loop until element is set, with timeout to avoid infinite loop.

If the element is still not found then look to see if the element you are trying to select is within a `form/frame/iframe` tagged parent element. If it is, update the html shown to include this/these, as these will need to be navigated as well in order to set the element.

---

**Show/Hide columns and options:**

You can click show hide as follows, and list the options and select a particular one as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClickShowHide()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .navigate "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&type=Intr&rslt=&recrs=b&recrs=a&age_v=&age=1&gndr=&intr=&titles=&outc=&spons=&lead=&id=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=&locn=&phase=0&phase=1&phase=2&fund=2&strd_s=&strd_e=&prcd_s=&prcd_e=&sfpd_s=&sfpd_e=&lupd_s=&lupd_e=&sort="
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("button[title='Choose columns to display from a list']").Click

        Dim optionsList As Object, i As Long
        Set optionsList = .document.querySelectorAll("button[aria-controls='theDataTable']")

        For i = 1 To optionsList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print optionsList.item(i).innerText
        Next

        optionsList.item(1).Click '<==select a partic option
       '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you left long enough for the page to load first? And is the element within a form/frame/iframe tag?

Comment: I don't think the url is a form, but the page before was (the page I'm working on is the search results of the form) and yeah the page is definitely loaded

Comment: Can you share more of the html or an URL? The selectors shown work for your HTML sample given.

Comment: And I'm trying to click the "Show Hide Columns" then select some options

Comment: Updated as required.